# Script blocked by provider because of execution time

Tags: i18n-l10n

Have moved my services to the new provider. 
Never had such a problem before but now my new provider seems to stop/kill/hang processes running for longer then 30s.

The problematic module seems to be:

- **Localization update** 7.x-2.0 Provides automatic downloads and updates for translations.

Once I run it, the whole service hanged so had to manualy disable it in the database.

It's a big problem for me as I used to run it periodically to update translations.

**The question is if is there any way to configure it to do not exceed the given 30s time limit?**

Comment: Ask your host what methods you have available to increase the execution time (user php.ini and max_execution_time for example). If not, and the module doesn't already provide a batched version of its functionality, you'll need to open a feature request for it to the issue queue, as it'll mean coding that new functionality into the module

Comment: I can not increase host limit, period. What is a batched version ?

Comment: Drupal provides a batch API that well-behaved modules use to perform long tasks. It breaks requests up so they have less chance of running into execution timeouts. If the module you're using runs long tasks, but doesn't use the batch API, your problem could solved by someone updating the module to use it. Not a trivial matter though, it'd take a couple of hours of coding and some more for testing. If the module already _does_ use the batch API, and it's still timing out, then quite simply you need to put the site on a host that lets you increase that limit, or has better hardware

Comment: Ok, got the point. Have found it's known problem ... https://www.drupal.org/node/1267652